# When is the transaction's timestamp set during the transaction flow?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Looking at the [block struture](https://blockchain-fabric.blogspot.com/2017/04/under-construction-hyperledger-fabric.html) and the [Proposal](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/fabric-client/lib/protos/peer/proposal.proto#L134) and [ProposalResponse](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/release-1.4/fabric-client/lib/protos/peer/proposal_response.proto#L35) protos, It may be reasonable to conclude the timestamp of the transaction is set by the endorser peers. But if that's the case how can the endorsers ensure determinism of the proposal response? Is there any notion of a global timestamp between peers? And if so, is it accesible from a chaincode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction timestamp is set in the transaction proposal by the submitting client, therefore it will be the same across all endorsing peers, and is only as reliable as the client submitting it. There is no global time across peers, only a global order of blocks and transactions. You can retrieve the timestamp that the client set by using the GetTxTimestamp() chaincode shim API.